# What does void(*)() mean in code

Tags: c++, c, void, shellcode

I saw this code today in some fb profile, and was not able to understand what is and how this is working:-

```
(*(void(*)()) shellcode)()
```

Can someone please explain me, what does above code mean ?

Full Code Snippet Below :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
          "\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

int main(void)
{
fprintf(stdout,"Length: %d\n",strlen(shellcode));
(*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shellcode is casted to a void function and then executed.

Comment: no... I can see, it's shell code, probably backdoor.. but wanted to know how does void(*) line interprets ?

Comment: @AdamS what does casted mean here ? bro .

Comment: @Johnsmith Basically "take this variable as something it's not defined as", thus the bytes in shellcode will be interpreted as a void function without arguments.

Comment: @jrok You most probably won't be able to run since memory will not be executable now a day.

Comment: @mathk memory not be executable ?

Comment: @Johnsmith: Modern operating systems prevent you from running arbitrary data as code, to protect against some common security issues. The code itself is marked as executable, but data isn't unless you specifically enable it, e.g. by using `mprotect(PROT_EXEC)` in Posix.

Comment: Go to http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ and disassemble the shellcode. It call a syscall execv that would replace the current running program by a shell `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a cast to a function pointer (with no returned result and no arguments). I prefer using `typedef` to define signature of such functions:

```
 typedef void plainsig_t(void);
```

then simply code

```
 (*(plainsig_t*)shellcode) ();
```

For function pointers, you don't need to dereference them, so it is shorter to just code:

```
 ((plainsig_t*) shellcode) ();
```

which basically calls the function whose machine code is located inside `shellcode` memory zone.

BTW, this is not strictly portable C. In principle, there is no guarantee that you can cast a data pointer to a function pointer. (On some weird processors -e.g. embedded microcontrollers, DSP, 1970s era computers-, code and data sit in different address spaces, or have different pointer sizes, etc....). But most common processors and ABI (x86-64/Linux, ARM/Android, ....) have the same address space for code and for data and accept casting function pointers to data pointers and vice versa.

Comment: if there is no result, than does it mean, the code in hex will never get executed and will never perform any command ?

Comment: @Johnsmith no result means no return value. It is indeed executed.

Comment: @Johnsmith - the code in hex will execute; it would be like calling a void function -- one that has no `return` statement.

Comment: No, the function gets called and executed for its side effects.

Answer (score 6):

This is one place that C and C++ differ.

In C it means a pointer to a function returning void and taking an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types.

In C++ it means a pointer to a function returning void and taking no argument.

The expression as a whole takes the address of `shellcode`, casts it to a pointer to function type, then invokes the function -- i.e., executes the op-codes in that string.

Comment: Which is exactly why it should be tagged with only one of the two.

Comment: @chris: I sort of agree, but in this case it's being invoked with no arguments, so it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 5):

`void(*)()` means "a pointer to a void function that takes no arguments." The line

```
(*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
```

is casting `shellcode` to such a function pointer, dereferencing the pointer (not actually necessary), and then calling the function.

Comment: than, what does it mean to add `shellcode)()` after `*void(*)()`

Comment: @Johnsmith - I think you were writing your comment while I was adding that information to my answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a function pointer. Type specifiers match declarations; so a function `void f()` has type `void()`; and a pointer to a function `void (*pf)()` has type `void(*)()`.

Note that, as with function declarations, it has slightly different meanings in C and C++. In C, the empty parentheses mean it has an unspecified number of parameters, while in C++ it means it has no parameters. However, that doesn't affect the meaning of the code.

This code reinterprets an array as a function and attempts to call it. Presumably, the array contains machine code to print a message, or format your hard drive, or something. On most modern platforms, this will cause a protection fault since the static data is (hopefully) not executable by default.

Answer (score 0):

In C a variable is declared as `int foo;`
, to declare a function we use `int foo( );` It means that the return type of the function is int. To declare a pointer we use `*foo`.

In the expression `(*(void(*)())0)()` we can see that

1. Assuming that the variable `fp` is a function pointer, we can use `(*fp)( );` to call the function, because `fp` is a function pointer, and `*fp` is the function pointed to by the pointer, so `(*fp)( );` can call the function.
2. Suppose `fp` is a pointer to a non-return value type, then the way to call it is `void (*fp)( )`, then the type of the `fp` variable is `void (*)( )`.
3. If we were to cast this type to a constant `shellcode`, then we use `( void (*)() ) shellcode`.
4. Now that the shellcode is cast to the type, in order to call the shellcode we use

   `( ( void (*)() ) shellcode )();`

---

Note: We can use typedef to replace the type name of the above expression

For example: `typedef void (*ff)( );` Therefore, the way to call a function can be written as:

`(*(ff) shellcode ) ( );`

from : https://www.codetd.com/en/article/14043929